# Can transfer data through Raiden network?

Tags: transactions, raiden

Is there a way to transfer data through Raiden Network. As i checked their Docs and whitepaper all its mentioned about ERC token transfer. i need to transfer a hash to Etherum rough Raiden network. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point Raiden is designed only for ERC20 transfers. There are plans to extend it to [generalized state channels](http://raiden-network.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec.html) and channels with multiple parties.

If by data you mean big files e.g. images or video then look into ipfs instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to transfer a hash that holds a set of data.Is there any other state Chanel that support data transfer?